Flaui inspector cannot detect the xpath on windows application
I am working on automation test scripting (FlaUI for Robotframework).
I need help on finding xpath by using the flaUI inspector.
"None" Xpath is detected on this kind of "Document" table grid element.
That element is clickable but I found no way to automate it.

